# Update record using scheduled apex

Tags: scheduled-apex

I have a question about scheduler.. If I use scheduled apex to update a record of custom object, will the record last modified also updated? or only the targeted field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a record is changed by any means, `Last modified Date` and `Last modified By` both will update.

In case of Schedule apex who runs the scheduler will be the user who would be assigned into `Last Modified By` field.

In some cases like Post install Script when technically there is no real user runs the script salesforce create a ghost user under which this script runs and `last modified by` assigned to this user.